# Can I download my iPhone app xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a quick question, I have lost the files and code for my iPhone app. I have my iTunes connect login details... is there any way of getting the code from my developers section?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

No, neither iTunes connect nor Apple Developer act as source control. You can get the provisioning profiles and create new certificates, but your code is yours to manage.

I would **very** strongly recommend looking into proper source control in the future (GitHub, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I'm afraid not. The "code" you upload to iTunes connect is actually your project's *binary*. You can't download this from the portal, and even if you could, there's no way to transcribe it back into your original application code.